# Error with sed on MAC OS X invalid command u

Tags: bash, shell, sed, osx, thunderbird

I have an error on MAC OS X when I'm using `sed`, which looks like so:

```
sed -i '' '/user_pref("mail.identity.id1.reply_on_top", 1);/ a\
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file", "/Users/nicolas.hulot/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file-rel", "[ProfD]../../../Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");
' ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/*.default/prefs.js
```

When I change the second and third line by another string like `'abcdefgh...'` it's good, but with this string which has a lot of specials characters it's too wrong.

The error which appears is:

> `sed: 3: "/user_pref("mail.identi ...": invalid command code u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newline` for `sed`'s `a`ppend is break it, so you have to backslash `newline` or sustitute by `\n` symbol:

```
sed -i '' '/user_pref("mail.identity.id1.reply_on_top", 1);/ a\
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file", "/Users/illias.seba/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");\
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file-rel", "[ProfD]../../../Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");\
' ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/*.default/prefs.js
```

or

```
sed -i '' '/user_pref("mail.identity.id1.reply_on_top", 1);/ a\
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file", "/Users/illias.seba/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");\nuser_pref("mail.identity.id1.sig_file-rel", "[ProfD]../../../Mail/V2/MailData/Signatures/signature.html");\n' ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/*.default/prefs.js
```